# How to get value from one field to another field

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I have two objects.

1. Requisition `SCMC__Requisition__c`
2. Purchase Order (PO) `SCMC__Purchase_Order__c`

There is a field in Requisition i.e *Requestor Notes to Buyer* `SCMC__Requestor_Notes_to_Buyer__c` which is a lon text datatype.

There is a field in Purchase Order i.e. *Buyer Notes* `SCMC__Buyer_Notes__c`.

So whatever value, I put in Requestor Notes to Buyer, I get the same value in Buyer Notes. But that is for one Requistion.  [image] Now, I want to put all the *Requestor Notes to Buyer values* of all **Requisitions** to Buyer Notes. So lets say, for example there are 5 Requisitions with diff values like abc, xyz, 123 so I want my **Buyer Notes** to be shown abc, xyz, 123.

I have to do this in my controller class. Should I create a list and store the values ? How am I suppose to proceed ?

Comment: Sus - you'll get more help with more information such as which of the two objects is the parent and which is the child?  Then, show your controller code with where you are getting stuck; SFSE tends not to write your code for you